# changing bootstrap progress bar color based on percentage

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I created a progress bar using Bootstrap and want the color to change dynamically based on percentage.  So far this is what my code looks like:

```
<div class="progress" style="height: {{c.options.bar_height}}px;">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active {{c.progress_bar_color}}" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={{c.data.percent_complete}} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{c.data.percent_complete}}; font-size: {{c.options.font_size}};">
      {{c.data.percent_complete}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

In my client controller, I have set the colors as such:

```
if(c.data.percent_complete<=50) {
    c.progress_bar_color = 'progress-bar-danger';
}  
if(c.data.percent_complete>50 && c.data.percent_complete<=75) {
    c.progress_bar_color = 'progress-bar-warning';  
}  
if(c.data.percent_complete>75 && c.data.percent_complete<=99.99) {
    c.progress_bar_color = 'progress-bar-primary';
}  
if(c.data.percent_complete==100) {
    c.progress_bar_color = 'progress-bar-success';
}
```

So far, the progress bar doesn't change color at all.  What am I missing to get this to work?

---

EDIT

I got rid of my client controller and added a ng-class:

```
ng-class="{'progress-bar-danger': c.data.percent_complete<'33', 'progress-bar-warning': c.data.percent_complete>='33' && c.data.percent_complete<'66', 'progress-bar-success': c.data.percent_complete>='66'}"
```

This works for every scenario, EXCEPT when it is 100%.  When the bar reaches 100%, for whatever reason, it changes to progress-bar-danger instead of progress-bar-success.  Any suggestions how to fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could try using `ng-class="c.progress_bar_color"` instead

Maybe this [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wakajzqe/) helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using uib-progressbar instead:

My client controller:

```
var value = c.data.percent_complete;
    var type;

    if (value <= c.options.danger_threshold) {
        type = 'danger';
    } else if (value > c.options.danger_threshold && value <= c.options.warning_threshold) {
        type = 'warning';
    } else if (value > c.options.warning_threshold && value <= c.options.primary_threshold) {
        type = 'primary';
    } else {
        type = 'success';
    }

    c.percentage_label = value+'%';
    c.type = type;
```

My revised HTML:

```
<uib-progressbar style="height: {{c.options.bar_height}}px;" class="progress-striped active" value="c.data.percent_complete" type="{{c.type}}">
    <div>
      <span style="font-size: {{c.options.font_size}};">{{c.percentage_label}}</span>
      <i ng-if="c.data.empty.length>0" class="fa fa-info-circle info m-l-xs" popover-placement="{{c.dynamicPopover.placement}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" uib-popover-template="c.dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-title="{{c.data.empty.length}} Required Fields Missing"></i>
    </div>
  </uib-progressbar>
```